# How do I include a .pdf_tex file in the align environment?

Tags: graphics, align

I am writing a math document which contains several pictures. My pictures are `.pdf_tex` files from Inkscape, and usually

```
\begin{figure}
\centering 
\input{<name>.pdf_tex} 
\end{figure}
```

is fine for including them. However, sometimes I would like my pictures to be part of an equation, e.g. (extremely simplified example) if I draw a circle, `circle.pdf_tex`, I might want to calculate its area by

```
\begin{align}
\text{Area}\left( \input{circle.pdf_tex} \right)=\pi r^2
\end{align}
```

but of course I cannot simply input `.pdf_tex` in the `align` environment.
Does anyone know a nice solution to this?

Comment: Why don't you can?

Answer (score 1):

It seems placing the \input into a \text-environment (and using aligned) works:

```
\begin{align}
\text{Area}\left( 
\begin{aligned}\text{\input{circle.pdf_tex}} \end{aligned} 
\right)=\pi r^2
\end{align}
```

does the trick.

Comment: More simply `\mbox{\input{circle.pdf_tex}}`, which is more efficient: `\text` typesets the same image four times for the different math styles. Also `align` is to be changed into `equation`, when there's only one line. Use `\text` for “Area”, which is right.